# Jboss AS7 resteasy POST is not working for UTF-8 character

Tags: unicode, utf-8, jboss, jboss7.x, resteasy

I have created an rest API which accept application/xml, but when any Russian character come in request its represented as ??????.

for example :  **Государственный академический** is coming as **??????????????? ?????????????**

I have tried to put

```
 <system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
    </system-properties>
```

This has not impact. and then I tried to put `@Consumes("application/xml;charset=utf-8")`

it also didnt worked.

and if i return same Russian character in response it works fine and displayed properly.
I am not sure why I am not able to receive Russian characters.

Environment:

- Jboss EAP 6.1.1.GA
- restasy  2.3.6.Final
- JDK 7

Comment: Does your client send the header ```Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8``` and ```Accept: application/xml;charset=utf-8```?

Comment: @lefloh Yes I did that also but it didn't worked :(

Comment: This should work normally… I pushed a [simple example to github](https://github.com/lefloh/restful-encoding). Can you test it with the Unit-Test?

Comment: @lefloh I tried your example and I am also doing same thing in my project. Test case is failing :(

Comment: And you are using UTF-8 in your IDE?

Comment: @lefloh how to do that? And this is happening in DEV and SYS clusters also where there is no IDE involved. So I don't think IDE is have any role in it. I am using IntelliJ

Comment: The example is working on my machine, so I’ve no idea which configuration disturbs this. File Encoding in IDEA can be changed via Settings->File Encodings. One last note: The system-properties you mentioned only affect the URI-Encoding. Your encoding-problems appear in the body, not the URL.

Comment: @lefloh yes correct its in body but I did not got any setting for body.